# Edit/update user profile in PHP Query

Tags: php, html

Database values wont update when I added email to the query. But everything works fine without the email. Weird.

Here's my update query:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE signup_and_login_users_table SET fullname = ?, username = ?, email = ?
WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $fullname, $username, $id, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Here is my insert:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT signup_and_login_users_table (fullname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $fullname, $username, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters to be bound should be at the same order

try this

```
<?php

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE signup_and_login_users_table SET fullname = ?, username = ?, email = ? WHERE id = ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $fullname, $username, $email, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your params order should be : `$stmt->bind_param("sssi", $fullname, $username, $email, $id);`

```
<?php

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE signup_and_login_users_table SET fullname = ?, username = ?, email = ? WHERE id = ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $fullname, $username, $email, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: s = string, s = string, s = string, i = interger

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your query only has 4 field names but you're binding 5 parameters. You left "ssi" out of your query.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
"INSERT signup_and_login_users_table (ssi, fullname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
```

assuming "ssi" is the field name

Comment: A lot of times, the id field (not ssi) is an auto-increment and when inserting a null (usually done by missing the field from the insert) then it's filled in for you.